# How to create a new column with percentiles?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to create a new column in a dataframe, with percentile values of a different column.

```
arr = np.random.randint(1,300,10)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns =['x'])
```

I can then find for example, the 50th percentile by:

```
np.percentile(df3['x'], 50)
```

What I'd really like to do is create another column, with which percentile each value in `df3['x']` falls into.

I tried a for loop, which just went completely wrong. So any advice here would be great.

This is basically what I'm looking for:

[image: This is basically what I'm looking for]

Comment: "I tried a for loop, which just went completely wrong." We would be happy to try to help you figure out how it "went completely wrong". However, we can only understand how things "went completely wrong" if we know specifically what actually happened, and how that is different from what is supposed to happen; and we can only tell you what is wrong with code if you show us the code.

Comment: It would also help if you showed an actual example input and the desired corresponding output.

Comment: I can't remember which code I've tried it was yesterday when I tried. But I've updated the post with an example image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you mean like this?
(make 5 discrete quantiles and add a column that indicates the corresponding quantile)

```py
df3['quantiles'] = pd.qcut(df3.x, 5)
```

*df3* then looks like this:

```
     x        quantiles
0  264   (247.2, 269.8]
1  198   (166.0, 208.8]
2  216   (208.8, 247.2]
3  269   (247.2, 269.8]
4  273   (269.8, 287.0]
5  236   (208.8, 247.2]
6  146  (64.999, 166.0]
7  287   (269.8, 287.0]
8  171   (166.0, 208.8]
9   65  (64.999, 166.0]
```

or if you want custom labels for the bins:

```py
df3['quantiles'] = pd.qcut(df3.x, np.linspace(0,1,11), labels=np.linspace(0.1,1,10))
```

```
     x quantiles
0  264       0.7
1  198       0.4
2  216       0.5
3  269       0.8
4  273       0.9
5  236       0.6
6  146       0.2
7  287       1.0
8  171       0.3
9   65       0.1
```

Comment: What that does is fill the whole percentile column with the 50th percent number of x.
What id like is for the percentile column to correspond to it's own row basically. So the first value in the percentile column would be which percentile the first value in x column falls into.

Comment: changed the answer accordingly

Comment: That last edit was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.